# How to create image of tally erp and run on docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, tally

Can we create/push any software image to docker server and available for other developers?

I want to install tally software on server and make available on anytime.

Comment: Hey @paresh  Any update on tally-Docker image ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store for your own developers to push and pull images, you can install and configure the docker registry, there is also docker hub which has features such as such as teams, organizations, web hooks, automated builds

More information on the following link,
https://docs.docker.com/registry/